# Ecore containment opposite

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf

Image the following: (<> indicates a black diamond, which refers to a composition in UML)

```
+---+ 0..1   * +---+
| A |<>--------| B |
+---+          +---+
```

I have class A and class B. A containment reference exists from A to B with multiplicity unbound. The opposite reference has multiplicity 0..1.

My question is: Isn't this opposite multiplicity wrong / impossible ?! Because in Ecore, the containment reference specifies that B can only exist if it as an A. Therefore the multiplicity from B to A is always 1, isn't it ?!

0..1 would mean that an instance of B can have an A or not.

UPDATE: my task is to transform the following UML diagram into Ecore

```
+---+ 0..1   * +---+ *     1  +---+
| A |<>--------| B |--------<>| C |
+---+          +---+          +---+
```

I am not sure how to map the UML composition to Ecore

- Containment reference from A to B, upperbound: -1
- Opposite reference B to A, lowerbound 0, upperbound 1
- Containment reference from C to B, upperbound: -1
- Opposite reference B to C, lowerbound = uperbound = 1

Am I right ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your UML is that A can contain many Bs, C contains many Bs,  and B can reference 0..1 As and exactly one B.

This UML diagram is incorrect because an instance of B cannot be shared (that is the meaning of composition). So the link B-C should also be 0..1 and in that case you can use containment from both A and C.

Answer (score 0):

It can be zero, if B is the root of an EMF Resource. An EMF Resource root never has any container. And any EMF model can act as a resource root.

Comment: but what if it is not the root element ?

Comment: If it is not the root element, _and_ it is serialized, then it must not be null. But it is not an error to set it 0..1, because there are cases when it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of B can exist without being contained in an A, but I'm pretty sure it can not be *persisted* in that state (using default XML/XMI persistence). In fact, you can get a valid model into this state:

- if you have some other object, C, with an external reference to B
- A (and by nature of its containment, B) and C are loaded into memory and all references are resolved
- A is edited to remove B
- C will now have a reference to an instance of B, but that instance will not have a container and C can not be persisted (you'll get an exception about "B does not exist in a resource").